# Unable to create new row in PostgreSQL database through MS Access frontend

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I have MS Access application as a frontend and PostgreSQL database as a backend. The problem is that when I want to create new row in database I get

Run-time error '3155': ODBC--insert on a linked table failed

I tried with a simple application. Only one table. The problem is still there.
This is the code:

```
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTest")

With rs

    .AddNew

.Update

End With

rs.Close
db.Close
```

It breaks on .Update. 
What could be the reason for such behaviour?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you dealing with ADODB or DAO recordsets ? Are the 2 libraries declared in your 'tools' window? Which one comes first? And what is the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to insert some values:

```
With rs    
    .AddNew
        .Fields("SomeField").Value = something
        .Fields("AnotherField").Value = somethingelse
    .Update
    .Close
End With
```

Try this for an ODBC connection:

```
With rs    
    .AddNew
        .Fields("SomeFieldThatCanBeNull").Value = Null
    .Update
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but this is not what I need. AddNew should reserve new row in table with ID but this isn't happening. Because of that I manually increment ID and save it to table.

Comment: It will work with an Access database where the ID is created at the insert while, I guess, Postgress first assignes the ID at the update. Try my edited answer.